# How to massively download gmail attachments

Tags: ruby, download, gmail, attachment

What is the best way to automatically download multiple email attachments on gmail from multiple emails (a lot) (preferably with filtering by Sender/Title) on Ubuntu linux? Should I go with a firefox attachment or is getmail4 reliable, or should I try some programmatic way (I can do Ruby, but not many other languages)?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, 

"Do your homework

Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!
Be specific

If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer."

Answer (score 1):

Consider reasking your question in a more specific manner. I managed to find

https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail

and

https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail

Both of these will allow you to access gmail with ruby, do a search and download the emails.

Comment: ajahongir, GMail now offers a rest api. Might want to consider using that and net/http, faraday, etc.

Comment: I wanted use once and needed fast solution. so I exteemly create monkeypatchs and have downloaded today all emails. so now I am parsing them :). gmail have an API and libraries for .net, java - not have for ruby :(.